# Django channels: Execute consumer code from django drf view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I have django app with drf view and I want to call consumer by its name from the view.

I'm using the following packages versions:

```
Django==4.2.5
djangorestframework==3.14.0
channels==4.0.0
```

the following code prints nothing:

**settings.py:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     ...
    'rest_framework',
    'drf_yasg',
    'channels',
]
```

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer",
    },
}
```

**consumers.py:**

```
class TestConsumer(SyncConsumer):

    def test_consumer(self, message):
        print('start consumer')
        job = Job.objects.get(id=message.get('job'))
        job.status = Job.JobStatus.RUNNING
        job.save()
        print('Finish consumer')
```

**routing.py:**

```
ChannelNameRouter({
    "test_consumer": TestConsumer,
})
```

**views.py:**

```
class TestAPIView(APIView):
    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        message = {"selected_indices": 'test', "session_search": 'search_test', "job": 1}
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)("test_consumer", message)
```